# Haskell: Read a data file as array for computations

Tags: haskell

## Set-up

I have a data file in the following format: 2D coordinates separated by a space on each line,

```
1.23 4.0
23.7 23.1
60.4 4.2
```

To parse this, I made the following function (which I would not mind feedback on): it takes the file's path as string, parses the lines and columns as doubles,

```
fileData :: String -> IO [[Float]]
fileData str = readFile str >>=
               \file -> return $ map ((map $ \x -> read x::Float) . words $) $ lines file
```

The ouput given the example file above is an `IO [[Float]]`:

```
[[1.23, 4.0],
[23.7, 23.1],
[60.4, 4.2]]
```

## Questions

What is the best way to handle this array, the output of `fileData`?  For example, how should one go about doing computations with values in this array?  Eventually, I will want to manipulate these values using hMatrix.

<strike>To obtain the zeroth element of the array `[1.23, 4.0]`, I tried running</strike>

```
main :: IO ()
main = fileData "file.txt" >>=
       \file -> print $ (flip (!!) 0) <$> file
```

but it returns the zeroth elements of each sub-array `[1.23, 23.7, 60.4]`, which matches with the value of <strike>`(print $ map (flip (!!) 0))` on the array as if was `[[Float]]`</strike> `print $ map (flip (!!) 0) xs`, where `xs` is the array as if it was `[[Float]]`.

## Update

I thought using fmap, as `(flip (!!) 0) <$> file` in `main` was necessary because of the type of `file` there, but it turns out that `file !! 0` works as intended; this makes `main` revised as:

```
main :: IO ()
main = fileData "file.txt" >>=
       \file -> print $ file !! 0
```

However, now I am confused as to what the type of `file` in `fileData "file.txt" >>= \file -> print $ file !! 0`.  I thought it was of type `IO [[Float]]` so applying `(!!)` would not work directly, because of the `IO` monad.  Is there a better way to think about this?

Comment: `(print $ map (flip (!!) 0))` is a compilation error.

Comment: Ah, right.  What I mean to say is: `print $ map (flip (!!) 0) xs`, where `xs` is the array of type `[[Float]]`.

Comment: lists aren't arrays. Are you asking how to convert those lists into an hmatrix matrix? Did you read the hmatrix docs?

Comment: No, I am not asking about how to convert those to hMatrix right now.  What I would like to know is how to better interact with the object `IO [[Float]]`.  For example, how do I go about getting the zeroth element of `[[1.23, 4.0], [23.7, 23.1], [60.4, 4.2]] :: IO [[Float]]` -- by which I mean `[1.23, 4.0] :: IO [Float]`?